# read data from multiple spreadsheets into database

Tags: openoffice-calc

I've got a whole directory of openoffice calc files, which are basically filled out versions of the exact same Template.

Now I would like to get the Data of a few cells of each file and put them into a MySQL database.

Is it possible to do this using OpenOffice Calc itself?

As this is a one-time job it does not matter how messy it gets and I would like to waste as little time on writing code as possible.

The only scripting language I have ready to use right now is PHP and I would be able to do it with PHP using a xml reader class, but I have never done that before and I don't want to waste my time on endless debugging so I figured I'd ask you guys first for better ideas.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anybody cares, here is how I did it in the end, no scripting was needed:

1. do Strg + A and Strg + C on the files in the folder to copy all file paths
2. paste into first column of new spreadsheet
3. use find&replace to replace all .ods file endings in the column with a unique placeholder
4. paste list of files into next column and repeat 3.
5. repeat for all columns
6. do a find&repalace to replace "\" with "/"
7. replace all placeholders with ".ods'#Table1.A1" where A1 stands for the cell that you want to get the data from
8. relplace "C:/" with "='file:///C:/" this might take a few seconds to process
9. copy everything to new file with paste special(Strg+Shift+V) so that only the values get pasted
10. import .ods into phpmyadmin

Comment: That sounds better than what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Create a LibreOffice Base file to connect to mysql.  Then write a macro in either [LibreOffice Basic](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) or [Python-UNO](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python).

1. [Open each file in Calc](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Handling_Spreadsheet_Documents_Files#Creating_and_Loading_Spreadsheet_Documents).
2. [Read the cells](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/27678/basic-function-to-return-cell-contents/).
3. [Do an SQL call](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=42882) to insert the data.

You may be able to do some of these things without macro code.  For example, if you can get all of the data into a single spreadsheet, then drag the data into the *Tables* area of the Base window, which will insert the data into mysql.

It's true that PHP could be used to unzip the ODS files and parse the XML for the values, but that sounds like it would require much more code and effort to develop.